# Can $5^n+6^n+10^n$ be a perfect power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

Related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4530582/82961) question:

> Can $f(n)=5^n+6^n+10^n$ with a non-negative integer $n$ be a perfect power ?

- It is not a perfect power for $0\le n\le 10^5$
- Analysis modulo $3$ reveals that a perfect square is impossible if $n\ge 2$ is even. Analysis modulo $8$ reveals that a perfect square is impossible , if $n\ge 1$ is odd. Hence the expression canoot be a perfect square.

What about cubes or higher perfect powers ? Considering the search limit, a perfect power of this form is extremely unlikely, but how can I make further progress towards a proof ?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, you have a multiple of $3$, so it would have to be a power of $3$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  It couldn't be $15^k$?

Comment: @B.Goddard the $6^n$ term is not a multiple of $5$. But yes I just realized the base could be a _multiple_ of $3$, so in that sense I am corrected.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  My point is that "it's a multiple of 3" doesn't imply that it's a power of 3.  How do you know it's not $21^k$?

Comment: So, my disclosure, see above. Oh yeah, this does mean I do not elevate to an answer.

Comment: Note also $3\not \mid n \Rightarrow 7\mid f(n)$

Comment: It's 1 mod 4 for n>=1 so either it's a square ( like all even powers) or the base is 1 modulo 4.

Comment: Combining the comment of Roddy MacPhee with Peter's discovery that all even powers are impossible we get that the base is of the form $1+4k$, with $k$ an integer. Also the congruence $f(n)\equiv 1 \pmod{20}$ implies that $1+4k \equiv 1 \pmod{20}$. Hence the perfect power is of the form $(1+20k)^{1+2e}$, with $k$ and $e$ integers.

Comment: The related link shows up as broken to me.  Presumably it defines "perfect power", but without a definition the question is significantly lacking.
"Related to this question:" 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4530582/82961

Comment: Thoughts: For $n\ge 2,\ f(n)\equiv 1 \bmod4,\ f(n)\equiv 1 \bmod 5 \Rightarrow f(n) \equiv 1 \bmod 20$ (see comments by Roddy MacPhee and jorisperrenet). For $n$ odd, $f(n) \equiv 0 \bmod 3,\ f(n) \equiv -1 \bmod 11$ (see first comment by Oscar Lanzi). So for $n$ odd, $f(n) \equiv 21 \bmod 660$, or $f(n)=(660k+21)^{2m+1}$.

Comment: $f(n) \equiv 1 \bmod 20$. For $n$ even, $f(n)\equiv 5 \bmod 6$. So for $n$ even, $f(n) \equiv 41 \bmod 60$ or $f(n)=(60k+41)^{2m+1}$ if the conjecture has solutions.

Comment: @KeithBackman If $f(n)\equiv 0\pmod 3$ and $f(n)$ is a perfect power then $f(n)\equiv 0\pmod{3^3}$.

Comment: A perfect power is usually defined as N^k where N and k are both integers ≥ 2.

Answer (score 5):

Since the problem seems very hard in full, here is a partial solution.

**Assuming the ABC conjecture**, there can only be finitely many $n$ such that $5^n + 6^n + 10^n$ is a perfect power. To see this, let $A = 5^n + 10^n$, $B = 6^n$, and $C = A + B$. Then we have
$$rad(A) \leq 5(1 + 2^n),$$
$$rad(B) = 6,$$
and if $C$ is a perfect power, we have
$$rad(C) \leq \sqrt{C}.$$
Thus, the quality of the triple(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) is
$$q(A,B,C) = \frac{\log C}{\log rad(ABC)} \geq \frac{\log C}{\frac{1}{2} \log C + \log 6 + \log 5 + \log (1 + 2^n)}.$$
As $C \geq 10^n$, we conclude that
$$q(A,B,C) \geq \frac{n \log 10}{n \cdot (\frac{1}{2} \log 10 + \log 2) + \log 30 + 2^{-n}}.$$
When $n \geq 15$, this is at least $1.1$. So ABC conjecture asserts that only finitely many $n$ can exist.

Answer (score 1):

We can rule out some $n$ using the following observation. Suppose that $f(n)$ is a perfect power dividing a prime number $p$. Since $f(n)$ cannot be a perfect square, $f(n)$ divides $p^3$. Note that if $p\ge 7$ then it divides none of numbers $5$, $6$, and $10$ then by Euler's theorem the sequence $\{f(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ modulo $p^3$ is periodic, and its period divides $\varphi(p^3)=p^3-p^2$.

Oscar Lanzi [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4534154/can-5n6n10n-be-a-perfect-power#comment9530644_4534154) that if $2\not|n$ then $3|f(n)$. Computer check shows that $3^3|f(n)$ iff $n\equiv 9\pmod {\varphi(3^3)}$.

Keith Backman [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4534154/can-5n6n10n-be-a-perfect-power#comment9531812_4534154) that if $3\not|n$ then $7|f(n)$. Computer check shows that $7^3|f(n)$ iff a residue of $n$ modulo $\varphi(7^3)$ (that is $294$) belongs to the set $49\cdot \{1,2,4,5\}$.

Moreover, if $n=6m$ then $$f(n)\equiv (5^6)^{m}+(6^6)^{m}+(10^6)^{m}\equiv 1+1+1=3\pmod 7$$ by Fermat Little Theorem. Then $f(n)$ cannot be a perfect cube, because each perfect cube is $0$ or $\pm 1$ modulo $7$.

Also we can rule out some impossible prime divisors of $f(n)$, namely, those prime $p\ge 7$ for which $p^3$ never divides $f(n)$. By Euler's theorem, for this suffices to calculate $f(n)$ modulo $p^3$ from $n=0$ to $n=\varphi(p^3)-1=p^3-p^2-1$. I wrote a program which checked primes $p\le 597$ and it ruled out the following values for $p$:

```
 17  19  29  37  41  43  61  71  79 
127 137 173 191 197 
229 233 241 251 277 283 
311 317 353 367 373 
401 409 421 433 439 449 461 463 467 479 
503 509 587 593
```

Comment: Your sequence of $5^m\bmod27$ is wrong: $-11\cdot5\equiv-1\not\equiv1$

Comment: So in fact $5^n+6^n+10^n$ is a multiple of $27$ when $n=9+18k$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Thanks for your check and sorry for the error. I fixed the answer.

Comment: There is no bound on the number of factors of $3$ in $f(n)$. For all $e$ we have $10^{3^e}\equiv1\bmod3^{e+2}$, which can be proven by induction (and using $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$). Also $6^{3^e}\equiv0\bmod3^{e+1}$, which is obvious since $3^e\geq e+1$. It can then be shown that $$f(3^e)\equiv5^{3^e}+0+1\equiv0\bmod3^{e+1}.$$ More generally, it seems that if a prime $p$ divides some $f(n)$, then any power of $p$ also divides some $f(n)$, but I don't know why. It does make it difficult to prove that infinitely many $f(n)$ are not perfect powers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda(m)$ be Carmichael's function, and let $h(m)$ be the factorization height, that is the greatest exponent in the prime factorization of $m$. The fundamental property of these two functions is $x^{h(m)+\lambda(m)}\equiv x^{h(m)}\bmod m$, for all $x$.

Here's a nice test for $e$'th powers. Suppose $\lambda(m)=qe$ is a multiple of the exponent $e$, and let $r=\lceil h(m)/e\rceil$. If $y$ is an $e$'th power (so $y\equiv x^e\bmod m$ for some $x$), then

$$y^{r+q}\equiv y^r\bmod m.$$

The point is that we don't need to calculate $m$ many powers $x^e$ and compare them to $y$; we can just calculate two powers $y^r$ and $y^q$. If the above congruence is violated, then $y$ cannot be an $e$'th power.

Now, we want to test for cubes, $e=3$. The sequence $f(n)=5^n+6^n+10^n\bmod m$ has a period $\lambda(m)$, for $n\geq h(m)$. For redundancy, we should take several different values $m_1,m_2,\cdots$ such that $\lambda(m)$ is a multiple of $e$, and take the least common multiple of the periods, $\Lambda=\text{LCM}(\lambda(m_1),\lambda(m_2),\cdots)$, and take $H=\max(h(m_1),h(m_2),\cdots)$. Then, for each $m$, the sequence $f(n)\bmod m$ has a period $\Lambda$, for $n\geq H$. So we only need to check $f(n)$ for $n<H+\Lambda$.

For $e=3$ we can take $m=7,13,19,31,37,61$ (thus $H=1$ and $\Lambda=180$) and do the computations to find that $f(n)$ is never a cube. (I.e. for each $n<181$ we have $f(n)^{r+q}\not\equiv f(n)^r\bmod m$ for at least one of the six $m$.)

For $e=5$ we can take $m=25,41,61,62$ (thus $H=2$ and $\Lambda=120$) to find that $f(n)$ is never a $5$th power.

For $e=7$ we can take $m=29,43$ (thus $H=1$ and $\Lambda=84$).

For $e=11$ we can take $m=23,67,89$ (thus $H=1$ and $\Lambda=264$).

For $e=13$ we can take $m=53,79,169$ (thus $H=2$ and $\Lambda=156$).

For $e=17$ we can take $m=103,137,239$ (thus $H=1$ and $\Lambda=2856$).

Then I got tired of visually scanning the lists of test results for $f(n)\bmod m$, trying to find efficient combinations of $m$ with relatively small $\Lambda$. Instead I just took all values of $m$, in order, adding another $m$ and restarting the computation whenever the tests failed for some $n$.

For $e=19$ it worked fine: $m=191,229,361$; $H=2$, $\Lambda=3420$.

For $e=23$ it produced a pretty long list: $m=47,94,139,141,188,235,277,278,282,329,376,417,423,461$; $H=3$, $\Lambda=1380$.

Proceeding in this way, I successfully tested all prime exponents up to $e=167$.

Then at $e=173$ my computer made no progress for several minutes; it had more than $40$ different values of $m$, with $\Lambda\approx28$million. I had to take a closer look again and try different things. It turned out that just two values suffice: $m=347,14533$; $H=1$, $\Lambda=14532$.

After that, I decided to allow only those $m$ for which $\lambda(m)$ divides $e\cdot2^2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$ or something like that, to keep $\Lambda$ from getting too big. I continued on to $e=499$ and got bored.

Comment: This is cool. Maybe some series of prime $e$'s (for instance, from some arithmetic progressions) can be ruled out analytically, by providing for them lists consisting of two or three numbers $m$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment too long to post in the comments section; it is NOT a complete answer. The question is: $f(n)=5^n+6^n+10^n=6^n+5^n(2^n+1)=r^s$? OP established $s$ cannot be even, so $s$ is odd and $s\ge 3$. Empirically, OP established that if solutions exist, $n$ must be large.

In this discussion, I address only the case $n$ is odd. I will show that when $n$ is odd: $27\mid n$; $3\mid r$; and $3\not \mid s$. **All conclusions are stated on the assumption that solutions to $f(n)=r^s$ exist,** or in the alternative, they may be viewed as necessary conditions for solutions to exist.

For odd $n$, it is well known that $(a+b)\mid (a^n+b^n)$. In particular, for odd $u,v$, $$2^{uv}+1=(2^u+1)\sum_{j=1}^v ((-1)^{j+1}2^{u(v-j)}$$ For odd $u$, $(2+1)\mid (2^u+1) \Rightarrow (2^u+1) \equiv 0 \bmod 3$

Working $\bmod 3$, note further that if $u,v$ are odd, then $$\sum_{j=1}^v ((-1)^{j+1}2^{u(v-j)}\equiv \sum_{j=1}^v ((-1)^{j+1}(-1)^{u(v-j)}=\sum_{j=1}^{v} ((-1)^{(uv+1)-j(u-1)}\equiv v \bmod 3$$ Note that the exponent $(uv+1)-j(u-1)$ is always even, without regard to the parity of $j$

Let $n=3^k(6m\pm 1)$. $2^n+1 = 2^{3^kv}+1$ where $v=6m\pm 1$, so $v\not \equiv 0 \bmod 3$, This ensures $n$ odd and all factors of $3$ appear in the $3^k$ term.

Lemma: For $k \ge 0$, $3^{k+1}\mid 2^n+1$

*Proof:* $2^n+1$ has a factor of $(2^{3^k})+1$
By Euler $\phi (3^{k+1})=2\cdot3^k$, so $2^{2\cdot3^k} \equiv 1 \bmod 3^{k+1}$, whence $(2^{3^k}) \equiv -1 \bmod 3^{k+1}$. Thus $(2^{3^k}+1) \equiv 0 \bmod 3^{k+1}$.

$6^n$ contains $n$ factors of $3$, and $5^n(2^n+1)$ has $k+1$ factors of $3$. Since $3^{k}v>k+1$, $r$ must contain factors of $3$ and $r^s$ must contain exactly $k+1$ factors of $3$. If $r = 3^wt$, then $w\cdot s=k+1$. This is true because after dividing out the most possible factors of $3$ from each term (i.e. $6^n;\ (2^n+1)5^n;\ r^s$), only one term may have any factors of $3$ remaining. However, $s\ge 3 \Rightarrow k\ge 2$. This shows that $3\mid r$ and $(3^{k+1}\ge 27) \mid n$

Last point: $9\mid n \Rightarrow 3\mid n$. Let $n=3a$, where $a$ is odd. Then $5^n+6^n+10^n=125^a+216^a+1000^a \equiv (-1)^a+(-1)^a+(-1)^a \equiv -3 \bmod 7$. This shows $7\not \mid r$. However, if $s=3b$, then $r^s=r^{3b}\equiv (\pm 1)^b \bmod 7$. The two sides of the equation are not equivalent $\bmod 7$ so it must be the case that $3\not \mid s$.

$3\not \mid s \Rightarrow s\ge 5 \Rightarrow k\ge 4$. So in fact, $243\mid n$, and as OP found empirically, $n$ is inconveniently large.

Comment: $2^{uv}+1=(2^u+1)\sum_{j=\color{blue}0}^{v\color{blue}{-1}} (-1)^{j}2^{\color{red}{uj}}$.

Comment: It is not clear why $r^s$ contains *exactly* $k+1$ factors of $3$, that is why $3^{k+2}\not|2^{n}+1$.

Comment: $3^{k+1}$ cannot divide $n$, because $n=3^k(6m\pm 1)$.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky Thanks for catching my summation error, which I have corrected (our indices run different, but the result is the same). I tried to clarify that the summation cannot contain more factors of $3$