# Frequent primes result from removing factors of $3$ from $2^{2m+1}+1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

While thinking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4534154/) I found that for $v$ of the form $6m\pm 1$ (that is, odd and having no factors of $3$), $2^{3^kv}+1$ is divisible by $3^{k+1}$; this includes the case $k=0$. Out of curiosity, I looked at what remains after all factors of $3$ are removed from $2^{3^kv}+1$, i.e. $R=\frac{2^{3^kv}+1}{3^{k+1}}$, which I name $R$ to avoid displaying the fraction itself every time I refer to it.

What I observed seems unusual to me. First, $R$ is a prime number roughly half the time ($11$ out of $21$). [OEIS A002589](https://oeis.org/A002589) reports the largest prime factor of $2^{3^kv}+1$, which matches the results I observe in the cases where my fraction is a prime number.

Second, I observed that $R \equiv 1 \bmod (3^kv)$ in the majority of cases ($16$ out of $21$). In the cases that $R \not \equiv 1 \bmod (3^kv)$, $R$ was composite. However, the reverse was not true: In some cases where $R$ was composite, $R \equiv 1 \bmod (3^kv)$

My ability to obtain prime factorizations for $R$ limited my observations to $3^kv \le 43$.

**My questions are:** Do the trends I observe continue for $3^kv > 43$, or is this just a coincidence confined to the few examples I have been able to examine? If the trends do continue, is there a mathematical explanation why $R$ is so frequently prime, and/or why $R \equiv 1 \bmod (3^kv)$ such a high fraction of the time?

**Addition for clarity** I define $v=6m\pm 1$. The case $v=1$ is permitted (but not $v=-1$, which makes no sense in context).

Comment: What is the range for $k$ and what is it for $v$ ?

Comment: Which primes of this form , except $19$ , did you find ?

Comment: @Peter In principle, ranges for $k$ and $v$ are unlimited, but due to the large factoring problems involved, I was only able to go up to $3^kv=43$. Remember, $k=0$ is permitted. Primes I found in that range are (in order of occurrence) $11; 43; 19; 683; 2731; 43691; 174763; 2796203; 715827883; 2932031007403$

Comment: Except $19$ , these are all primes of the form $\frac{2^n+1}{3}$ , so-called Wagstaff-primes. Maybe , the list is then already complete ?

Comment: It certainly is possible that the primes I describe are primarily Wagstaff primes (thanks to @Peter for alerting me to this class). If so, that would mean that all numbers of the form $\frac{2^{3^kv}}{3^{k+1}}$ are composite for $k\ge 1$. The exponent $9$ is one exception, yielding the prime $19$. Larger exponents to be examined would have the form $9+18t$. The exponent $27$ yields a composite, and exponents $45$ and larger are beyond my ability to test for primality.

Comment: For $1\le k\le 10$ and $1\le v\le 3\ 000$ with the restriction $v\equiv \pm1 \mod 6$ , the only prime is $19$. I guess , we can find algebraic factors or similar in the other cases , but I have not yet worked it out.

Comment: For $k\ge 2$ , we have factor $19$ (follows from $19\mid 2^9+1$) and for $k=1$ and $v\ge 5$ coprime to $6$ we have nontrivial factor $2^q+1$ , where $q$ is the smallest prime factor of $v$. So, in fact , $19$ is the only prime of this form not being a Wagstaff-prime.

Comment: @Peter Put your last comment in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: This is because $(2^p+1)/3$ is a Fermat probable prime, strong probable prime, and Primover simply because it is a Zsigmondy number